# python requests is slow

Tags: python, download, urllib2, python-requests, urllib

I am developing a download manager. Using the requests module in python to check for a valid link (and hopefully broken links).
My code for checking link below:

```
url = 'http://pyscripter.googlecode.com/files/PyScripter-v2.5.3-Setup.exe'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False) # this line takes 40 seconds
if r.status_code==200:
    print("link valid")
else:
    print("link invalid")
```

Now, the issue is this takes approximately 40 seconds to perform this check, which is huge.
My question is how can I speed this up maybe using urllib2 or something??

Note: Also if I replace `url` with the actual URL which is 'http://pyscripter.googlecode.com/files/PyScripter-v2.5.3-Setup.exe', this takes one second so it appears to be an issue with requests.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not all hosts support `head` requests. You can use this instead:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
```

This actually only download the headers, not the response content. Moreover, if the idea is to get the file afterwards, you don't have to make another request.

See [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) for more infos.

Comment: hey thanks doukremt...indeed it was showing 404 even when the item was there in some situations... thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Don't use `get` that actually retrieves the file, use:

```
r = requests.head(url,allow_redirects=False)
```

Which goes from 6.9secs on my machine to 0.4secs