# Python requests module is very slow on specific machine

Tags: python, python-requests

I've experienced too slow execution of Python requests on some machines and with specific user while other tools (for instance curl) are quite fast. Strange thing is that if run the script as another user then it runs as expected. If I run the script on my machine (both Windows or Linux) then it runs as expected too. Problematic machines are Windows 2008 servers on Hyper-V. I usually use POST request but both POST and GET are affected. For the demonstration I've created simple script with GET request. All requests take about 4.8s but it should take about 0.03s (virtual machines are not so powerful).

```
[imports and logging configuration omitted]

log.info("Started ...")

start = time.time()
response1 = requests.get("http://10.50.30.216:8080/sps/api/version")
assert response1.status_code == codes.OK
log.info("Using requests: %.3fs" % (time.time() - start))

start = time.time()
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("10.50.30.216:8080")
conn.request("GET", "/sps/api/version")
response2 = conn.getresponse()
assert response2.status == codes.OK
log.info("Using httplib: %.3fs" % (time.time() - start))

log.info("Finished ...")
```

Output when logged as problematic user (unfortunately I must use that user). See that requests module waits 4.523s before opening a connection while httplib module proceeds immediately.

```
2015-09-11 14:50:00,832 - INFO - myscript - Started ...
2015-09-11 14:50:05,355 - INFO - requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.50.30.216
2015-09-11 14:50:05,364 - DEBUG - requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - "GET /sps/api/version HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2015-09-11 14:50:05,365 - INFO - myscript - Using requests: 4.533s
2015-09-11 14:50:05,374 - INFO - myscript - Using httplib: 0.008s
2015-09-11 14:50:05,375 - INFO - myscript - Finished ...
```

Output when logged as another user. Note that both users have Administrator privileges but the second user is only temporary and only on one machine so I can't use solve this issue by switching users.

```
2015-09-11 14:57:45,789 - INFO - myscript - Started ...
2015-09-11 14:57:45,799 - INFO - requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.50.30.216
2015-09-11 14:57:45,806 - DEBUG - requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - "GET /sps/api/version HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2015-09-11 14:57:45,809 - INFO - myscript - Using requests: 0.021s
2015-09-11 14:57:45,815 - INFO - myscript - Using httplib: 0.004s
2015-09-11 14:57:45,815 - INFO - myscript - Finished ...
```

I've read [Python requests are slow #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780679/python-requests-is-slow) and [Python requests are slower thann curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996177/python-requests-module-get-post-various-rest-clients-requests-taking-longer-t) but it does not apply to my problem.

Comment: Try profiling it: `python -m cProfile your_script.py`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/582337/1084416).

Comment: This could be related to [pyOpenSSLl issue #137](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/137). To confirm or rule that out, could you please check whether `python -c "import OpenSSL"` is already slow, or just the actual request? (Also see [`requests` #2372](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2372))

Comment: Thanks for a reply but I don't think it's my issue because 1) Requests doing well when run as another user or on my laptop. 2) Each http request takes almost 5 sec even if there are some consecutive requests in one method. Only the first request would be slower if my issue was caused by import issue, right?

Answer (score 15):

For anyone reading this and using `localhost` in their URL, I resolved this issue by changing it to `127.0.0.1`.

If this resolves the problem, it's a DNS problem, and it's not a requests problem.

Answer (score 5):

There could be many things slowing the request down. Anything from DNS lookup, throttling etc.

Try getting some more information by turning requests debug logging on

```
logging.basicConfig() 
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
```

Comment: Thanks for a hint. I've modified my example (added logging and another http request) in my question. I've added output from different users on the same machine to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem... After a lot of debugging with authors, we concluded that the cause lies in proxy detection code...

So, once I implemented this, it resolved my similar problem: [requests: how to disable / bypass proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521535/requests-how-to-disable-bypass-proxy)

Authors are aware of the problem, and they have fix in works, and it should be released soon:  https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/2992 ...

Hope it helps...

cheers
Jaka

Comment: has it been released yet?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem.  After investigation determined that python's internal call to `socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):` was causing the delay.

In my configuration, I was on a Mac, OS/X 10.11. `host` was `dev.local`, and I had the relevant entry in `/etc/hosts`, pointing to a virtual box machine setup on host-only network.

```
192.168.56.101 dev.local
```

After banging my head for an hour or two, realized that hostnames ending with `.local` was the actual issue (despite the `/etc/hosts` entry).

This eventually lead me to https://superuser.com/questions/539849/long-lookup-times-for-local-in-hosts-file.  And voilà, avoiding made up host names with `.local` was all I needed.

I do realize this isn't the problem here -- `10.50.30.216` obviously doesn't end with `.local`!  But since this question was one of the most relevant ones I ran into looking for an answer to my problem, I thought I'd post an answer here.