# Request (or httplib2.request) taking too long to return status code

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if some file links are up or not. I've tried with requests library:

```
import requests
url = 'http://releases.libreelec.tv/LibreELEC-RPi2.arm-9.0.1.img.gz'
print(requests.get(url).status_code)
```

And also with httplib2:

```
import httplib2
url = 'http://releases.libreelec.tv/LibreELEC-RPi2.arm-9.0.1.img.gz'
http = httplib2.Http()
resp = http.request(url)[0]
print(resp.status)
```

As the link is good.. it takes too long (I've never waited it to finish) to return a '200' status code. It works fine for forbidden (403) code. The point is i need it to be fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fast:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
```

ref:[python requests is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780679/python-requests-is-slow/15781814)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get response code only, you can use `requests.head`:

```
import requests
try:
    r = requests.head('http://releases.libreelec.tv/LibreELEC-RPi2.arm-9.0.1.img.gz')
    print(r.status_code)
except:
    print('problem')
```

As shown in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140661/what-s-the-best-way-to-get-an-http-response-code-from-a-url), it should be faster as it gets only head, however please check if it is fast enough for your purpose.

Comment: for the specific situation, I've tried 'head' before.. it returns 200 for 403 status codes, for some reason.